# SWIFT: CDA to iOS 10 Health app

Tags: swift, healthkit, cda

Is there any way to send a xml file (CDA) to health app from another application? Because my application is getting a xml file from a source and I want to send it directly to the new health app (iOS 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an [HKCDADocumentSample](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkcdadocumentsample) and save it with an [HKHealthStore](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkhealthstore).

Comment: Do you have any idea how do I access and display all available health records stored in healthkit?

Answer (score 0):

First, check for authorization

```
(void) checkForAuthorization  {
  if ([HKHealthStore isHealthDataAvailable]) {
     NSSet *setRead = [NSSet setWithObjects [HKObjectTypedocumentTypeForIdentifier:HKDocumentTypeIdentifierCDA], nil];
     NSSet *setWrite = [NSSet setWithObjects:[HKObjectType documentTypeForIdentifier:HKDocumentTypeIdentifierCDA], nil];
     [_store requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:setWrite readTypes:nil completion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
     if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
     } else if (success) {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addDocumentToHealthApp) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
     }
       NSLog(@" Success = %@",success? @"YES" : @"NO");
     } ];
   } else {
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Health Kit not supported in device." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
  }
```

}

Second, add Record wmthod this will add a Health record to health app.

```
(void) addRecordToHealthApp
 {

NSURL *cdaPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample" withExtension:@"xml"];

NSString*stringPath = [cdaPath absoluteString]; 
    NSData *dataOfCDAFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringPath]];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
int daysToAdd = 7;
NSDate *newDate1 = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];

NSError *err;
HKCDADocumentSample *doc = [HKCDADocumentSample CDADocumentSampleWithData:dataOfCDAFile startDate:[NSDate date] endDate:newDate1 metadata:nil validationError:&err ];

UIAlertView *alert;
if (err) {
    alert  = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:err.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}





[_store saveObject:doc withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog("Stored %@",success?@"YES":@"NO");
}];

}
```

Comment: Can you do it in swift language?